# domain A IP is changing, from one to another

Tags: domain-name-system, ip

When I was installing SSL on website, I added new dedicated IP and sub-domain: crm.lawfirm.org.ua. lawfirm.org.ua is pointed to xname dns server and then to a hosting dns - by arvixe. For "crm" subdomain I added A - pointing to new dedicated IP. The problem is that after 3 days sometimes its changing IP to new and it works, and sometimes goes back to old. ping.eu for example showing right IP for monday and tuesday, while others not.

Comment: Most likely it's a caching problem, which may take 7 days to resolve itself.  Beyond that we need to see actual A & CNAME records to help, not enough info is provided.

Answer (score 2):

Have you recently changed your nameservers?  If I ask `ns0.xname.org`
about the nameservers for `lawfirm.org.ua`, I see two sets of servers
listed:

```
$ host -t ns lawfirm.org.ua ns0.xname.org
Using domain server:
Name: ns0.xname.org
Address: 195.234.42.1#53
Aliases: 

lawfirm.org.ua name server ns2.palm.arvixe.com.
lawfirm.org.ua name server ns2.xname.org.
lawfirm.org.ua name server ns0.xname.org.
lawfirm.org.ua name server ns1.palm.arvixe.com.
lawfirm.org.ua name server ns1.xname.org.
```

I get a different ip address for `crm.lawfirm.org.ua` depending on
which servers I ask.  Compare this:

```
$ host crm.lawfirm.org.ua ns0.xname.org
Using domain server:
Name: ns0.xname.org
Address: 195.234.42.1#53
Aliases: 

crm.lawfirm.org.ua has address 69.72.152.131
```

To this:

```
$ host crm.lawfirm.org.ua ns1.palm.arvixe.com
Using domain server:
Name: ns1.palm.arvixe.com
Address: 69.72.152.130#53
Aliases: 

crm.lawfirm.org.ua has address 69.72.152.155
```

It looks as if you may need to clean up the list of nameservers at
`xname.org`.

Comment: Very nice, I assumed "lawfirm" was a placeholder for the actual name!